# how to cast multiple integers as a ctypes array of c_ubyte in Python

Tags: python, types, casting, initialization, ctypes

How does one convert a string of colon-separated hexadecimal numbers into a ctypes array of c_ubyte?  According to the [ctypes docs](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes#type-conversions), I can cast a hard-coded collection, like so:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> x = (c_ubyte * 6) (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
>>> x
<__main__.c_ubyte_Array_6 object at 0x480c5348>
```

Or, like so:

```
>>> XObj = c_ubyte * 6
>>> x = XObj(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
>>> x
<__main__.c_ubyte_Array_6 object at 0x480c53a0>
```

However, I cannot figure how to cast a variable list, like one generated from splitting a string, for example:

```
>>> mac = 'aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff'
>>> j = tuple(int(z,16) for z in mac.split(':'))
>>> j
(170, 187, 204, 221, 238, 255)
>>> x = (c_ubyte * 6) (j)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required
>>> XObj = c_ubyte * 6
>>> x = XObj(j)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that in the first example you provided, you've used ctypes correctly by giving 6 arguments to XObj call, and in the second example (with mac address), you try to call the same object `c_ubyte * 6`, giving it a tuple, but not 6 values, so convert it using `*args` notation:

```
from c_types import c_ubyte

mac = 'aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff'
j = tuple(int(z,16) for z in mac.split(':'))

converted = (c_ubyte * 6)(*j)  # *j here is the most signigicant part
print converted
```

And the result is:

```
<__main__.c_ubyte_Array_6 object at 0x018BD300>
```

as expected.

Comment: Thanks!  That's exactly what I needed.  BTW, Would you update your answer to include a single-line version for splitting, parsing, and converting the string into a c_ubyte array?  Like so: `x = (c_ubyte * 6)(*tuple(int(z,16) for z in 'aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff'.split(':')))`

Comment: @Trevor, I'm not a code-whole-program-in-one-line maniac, I prefer readability ;)

Comment: Fair enough.  Maybe it's my Perl upbringing that keeps me looking for brevity.  :)  Anyway, your answer is just what I needed.  Thanks!